# The import gwtupload cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, gwtupload

I create sample application of `gwtupload`. https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/ Its working fine with the `.jar` I downloaded from project home.

But for my custom requirement I downloaded project from `git` https://github.com/manolo/gwtupload and made changes as per my requirement and created `.jar` file. Then I imported it to my project and included in classpath. Even eclipse is not giving any error in editor mode. But when I debug and open URL its giving me following error.

```
[ERROR] [uploadtest] - Line 3: The import gwtupload cannot be resolved
[ERROR] [uploadtest] - Line 53: SingleUploader cannot be resolved to a type
[ERROR] [uploadtest] - Line 54: IUploader cannot be resolved to a type
```

Tried stackoverflow thread [Eclipse error: "The import XXX cannot be resolved"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322893/eclipse-error-the-import-xxx-cannot-be-resolved) but didn't help me out.

**Do I need to create `.jar` file with other parameters than creating `.jar` using Export in eclipse?**

Comment: Have you addes source files (*.java) to your jar?

Comment: no...let me try that. Nice catch man.

Comment: Why do you want to change the standard way of generating libraries? Usually any open-source project uses an opensource tool (maven, ant, gradle) to produce the distribution files, and the maintainer takes care that running a single command everything works. Depending on an IDE to produce the product is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should export the .jar with "Java source files and resources". [image]

Comment: I am happy that worked for you:) Explanation in simple words: GWT allows you to write Java code, which is compiled into JavaScript. The tool which is doing the magic is GWT Compiler. The Input to the GWT compiler are "Java files", and the Output is highly optimized "JS + HTML" code. Therefore if you want to use external JAR's, the GWT Compiler needs to know how the Java code (from this jar) looks like.   You can read more here: http://www.gwtproject.org/learnmore-sdk.html

Answer (score 0):

Gwtupload is a maven project, so the easiest way to produce the .jar is just open a command-line session, change to the gwt-upload/core folder and run:

```
 mvn clean package
```